# Android Studio 3.1 design preview not showing anything (buttons, text, etc.)

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-studio-3.0

When creating a new project in AS with an empty activity, I used to be able to drag and drop textviews and buttons onto the design preview to add them (for my first project). However, now for some reason they aren't showing up anymore in the design tab, not even the default "Hello World!" text that it starts with.

New components give the error "This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints."

After searching for solutions, I have tried:
- restarting AS and computer
- reinstalling
- Force Refresh Layout
- Creating New Projects
- Right clicking Design -> Infer Constraints (I was not able to find this option)

Other solutions given were just images that have since expired/been removed.

I don't know what I am doing different from the first project I made and new ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** Right Click on the Component, Then go to Constraint Layout and click Infer Constraints

Or

*** Replace Constraint Layout with a Relative Layout

UPDATE

Go to res/values/styles.xml file...

on line 4, its always...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Change this with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: There is no constraint layout option when I right click.

https://imgur.com/a/kneXYH4

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Is there a reason it isn't the second option by default?

Comment: saved the day!  I was wondering if I have a bad day after debugging bug in VS and now in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**Open Your build.gradle(Module: app)**

**Write**

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

**instead of**

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'

**Hope it will Help You**